# What is perceptually uniform color space and how LAB color space is perceptually uniform?

Tags: image, image-processing, color-space, lab-color-space

What is perceptually uniform color space ?
how Lab color space is perceptually uniform and device independent?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming issue.

Comment: ya i know but i need  to know this before using it in algoritm

Comment: Perhaps, but it's still not a concrete programming problem and thus off topic for Stack Overflow. The concept is [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#Tolerance) — if a color space is perceptually uniform, it means that a change of length *x* in any direction of the color space would be perceived by a human as the same change.

Comment: okk i get  it.from nxt time i will keep that in mind

Comment: For someone searching what is perceptually uniform color space. https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/perceptually-uniform-color-spaces/index.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlDySNpGbyc

Answer (score 5):

slhck is right: a perceptual uniform color space ensures that the difference between two colors (as perceived by the human eye) is proportional to the Euclidian distance within the given color space. *Lab* was created to satisfy the perceptual uniformity property.

However, this property is **satisfied only locally**. For distant colors, the perceived difference is no more in accordance with the Euclidian distance. Therefore, new distances were defined, such as [**deltaE, CIE76, CIE94, CIE2000**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) in order to satisfy both local and global perceptual uniformity.